# multiple inputs for file upload in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

i want to upload multiple file selected in different inputs field. my form looks like

```
<form action="blog_write_validate.php" method="post" id="form"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label>Image if any</label><input type="file" name="title[0][img]"  id="file1"><br>
   <label>Image if any</label><input type="file" name="title[1][img]" id="file2"><br>
   <label>Image if any</label><input type="file" name="title[2][img]" id="file3"><br>
</form>
```

blog_write_validate.php page is

```
if(isset($_POST['subm']))
{
extract($_POST);
$i = 3; $j=0;
foreach($_POST['title'] as $diam )
{
    $imgname = $diam['img'];

        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png","GIF","JPEG","JPG","PNG");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);

        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
        {
            echo "in upload ";
            $newfilename = time() . '.' . end($temp);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][0],"blog/".$newfilename."");
            echo "File uploaded <br>";
        }
        else
        {
            print "<br> ".$_FILES["file"]["type"]."";print "<br>";
            print "<h2>Invalid image. File should be less than 2MB </h2>";
            header("Location: blog_write.php" );exit;
        } 
     }
```

i want to know how i can get these file name types fromm the array. ihave tries things like $imagename = $diam['img']  , $imagename = $_FILES["file"]["name"]['img'];
plesase tell me how to get these file name so that I can upload correctly

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there. Replace 
`foreach($_POST['title'] as $diam )` with `foreach($_FILES['title'] as $diam )`.

In addition, you need to update logic underneath the foreach loop also to get the desired results.

When HTML form is posted, any elements's name is passed via $_POST super global. Same is the case for $_FILES.
You have three file input types and $_FILES is populated with **name** of those inputs e.g. $_FILES["title"]

Comment: if i had many other inputs field like text. then what should be in foreach statement

Comment: If I got you correctly, all file input types named "title" will be grouped together. So they can be traversed via a single loop. If their name is different you will need separate loop for each group. Or you can try to use singly loop and check for group "name" inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = $_FILES['file'];
$count = sizeof($name);

for($a=0;$a<$count;$a++)
{
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"][$a] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$a] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$a] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$a] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$a] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$a] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$a] < 100000000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
        {
            echo "in upload ";
            $newfilename = time() . '.' . end($temp);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$a],"blog/".$newfilename."");
            echo "File uploaded <br>";
        }
}
```

Comment: what will be the temp variable here

Comment: first you check on server all file get in server write code "echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES);exit;" this code ischeck all file geting on server post